# Output is not what I think it should be

Tags: python

This is my first question on the site, I highly appreciate any feedback. The book I'm working on by Guttag from MIT says that the program would print the following:

```
x=4
z=4
x = abc
x=4
x=3
z = <function g at 0x15b43b0> 
x = abc
```

My question is, why does the first x displayed have a value of 4, it is
binded to 3, and is printed before the function is called, and is in the
main name space, not local to function. Please, if anyone can explain to
me why the output printed is what it is, it would be of great help, thanks in advance.

```
def f(x):
    def g():
        x = 'abc'
        print 'x =', x 
    def h():
        z=x
        print 'z =', z 
    x=x+1
    print 'x =', x 
    h()
    g()
    print 'x =', x 
    return g
x=3
z = f(x)
print 'x =', x 
print 'z =', z 
z()
```

Comment: Title is too generic, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my explanation:

1. x is set to 3
2. f is called with the input x = 3
3. Then, `x=x+1` sets x (the local variable) to 4.
4. The first print prints x=4

To answer your concerns:

1. x **is** a local variable to f, because f takes x as an argument.
2. f is called before x is printed `z = f(x)` calls f, and returns a *function* (g).
3. The line `z()` isn't calling f. It is calling the function that f returned with `return g`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, highly appreciated. Got it now, so assigning a function call to a variable actually calls the function, correct? Everything else makes sense from there.